# AS3 iOS Scrolling with movieclip

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, scroll

I ran into this problem that flash will return me a 
1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: mouseY

I'm trying to scroll a movieclip in a separate class which I have placed into a container
which is up till now not working!

Help will be appreciated!

P.S I followed this tutorial http://forums.adobe.com/thread/892372

My scroll Class:

```
package  {
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.ui.Mouse;

public class Scrolling {

    private var Touchscroll:Point = new Point;
    private var completeTween:Boolean;
    private var finalMouseY:int;
    private var mc:MovieClip = IconSpawn.container;
    private var currentY:mouseY = new mouseY;

    public function Scrolling() {
        // constructor code
        mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,onDown1)

    }

    public function onDown1(evt:MouseEvent):void
    {
        completeTween = false;
        //stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,onUp1);

        MovieClip(evt.currentTarget).addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,tweenF);
    }

    public function tweenF(e:Event):void
    {
        //var mc:MovieClip = MovieClip(evt.currentTarget);

        if(completeTween)
        {
            mc.y = .5*(mc.y + Math.min(800,finalMouseY));

            if(Math.abs(mc.y - Math.min(800, finalMouseY)) <1)
            {
                e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,tweenF);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            mc.y = .5*(mc.y + Math.min(800, mouseY));
        }

    }
    public function onUp1(evt:MouseEvent):void
    {
        completeTween = true;
        finalMouseY = currentY;
        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,onUP1);
    }

}
```

}

Edited code:

```
package  {
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.ui.Mouse;

public class Scrolling {

private var Touchscroll:Point = new Point;
private var completeTween:Boolean;
private var startMouseY:int;
private var finalMouseY:int;
private var mc:MovieClip = IconSpawn.container;
//private var CurrentY = mouseY

public function Scrolling() {
    // constructor code
    mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,onDown1)

}

public function onDown1(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    startMouseY = mouseY;
    completeTween = false;
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,onUp1);

    MovieClip(evt.currentTarget).addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,tweenF);
}

public function tweenF(e:Event):void
{
    //var mc:MovieClip = MovieClip(evt.currentTarget);

    if(completeTween)
    {
        mc.y = .5*(mc.y + Math.min(800,finalMouseY));

        if(Math.abs(mc.y - Math.min(800, finalMouseY)) <1)
        {
            e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,tweenF);
        }

    }
    else
    {
        mc.y = .5*(mc.y + Math.min(800, mouseY - startMouseY));
    }

}
public function onUp1(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    completeTween = true;
    finalMouseY = mouseY - startMouseY;
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,onUP1);
}

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your line 15: `private var currentY:mouseY = new mouseY;` you've taken the public property of a Display Object and tried to turn it into a class. Don't do that!!

Just declare CurrentY as an instance variable. In your constructor, or later, set `CurrentY = mouseY`.

Comment: Now Flash just produces a ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable mouseY is not defined at Scrolling/onUp1() and onDown1()

Here's my updated code

Comment: I got Access of undefined property mouseY, stage and onUP1. 
On Lines 25,27,48,55,56,56

Comment: Well, look at your code:  you've got    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,onUp1); and then you've got stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,onUP1);    You're gonna have to do some of this work yourself, Josh!    There should be no problem with mouseY. Please check again.